# Geometric Interpretation of these equations of motion?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, integration

I was reading my Engineering Mechanics book, and it derived some strange looking integrals I'll have to apply. I could memorize them, but I'd rather understand them - then I won't have to memorize.

A few words mentioning Leibniz notion, and viola - we have these relationships:

$$\int_{v_0}^vdv=\int_0^ta_cdt$$
$$\int_{s_0}^sds=\int_0^t(v_0+a_ct)dt$$
$$\int_{v_0}^vvdv=\int_{s_0}^sa_cds$$

I can manipulate them given appropriate data, but they don't really *mean* much to me.  (I *do* easily understand things like $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$,however).

I anyone could point me to website that discuss or even just show me how to derive these, I would really appreciate it - I find it easier to understand geometric interpretations, but I would appreciate any knowledge you would be willing to share.

Comment: How did you get to this ''Engineering Mechanics'' book without learning basic kinematics first!?! Read _Fundamentals of Physics_ by Resnick, Halliday and Walker, before jumping into any engineering textbook.

Comment: Took it a very long time ago for the record.. I guess I'll hit those chapters again... I only remember seeing one of these, mabye I'm wrong though...